# Blob creation using Hibernate and Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I'm using Spring 4.2.3, Hibernate 5.0.4, JPA 2.1 for purpose of self training in case of ORM. Today I was learning how to store [Blob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) in Oracle 11.2.0.4 DB.

In my application I have Service and Dao layers.

**Problem:**
Why should I create [Blob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) instance using [Hibernate.getLobCreator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#getLobCreator-org.hibernate.Session-) which requires current session? Why it is not possible using [Hibernate.createBlob][3] any more (without accessing current session) ?

In some cases I may need transient domain model with [Blob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) field initialized without need to persist it in DB using Dao.

Is it because of (as written in [Blob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) JavaDoc) :

> A Blob object is valid for the duration of the transaction in which is was created.

Sorry for asking silly question but I was unable to find satisfying answer.

[3]: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#createBlob(java.io.InputStream, long)

Comment: or more to the point, why is it necessary to use vendor-specific methods just to persist a Blob, when other JPA providers don't require it?

Comment: Why do you want to manually create a blob? For this there is the [`@Lob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html) annotation... Just add it to a `byte[]` or `String` parameter and be done with it. Don't mess around with (B/C)Lobs yourself (that was how it was done long time ago).

Comment: @M.Deinum thank You for answer. Do You mean that byte[] or String should be used in mapping instead of (B/C)Lobs ? However in [Hibernate 5.0 Lobs Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html_single/#basic-lob) java.sql.Clob field is also used.

Comment: The mapping will be done for you. Do you really want your entities to rely on sql specific types? Which basically ties your whole application to sql. But the `@Lob` annotation will also work on `Blob` or `Clob` field but do you really want that, as it makes it complexer to write those things.

Comment: I don't want to ;) I was just thinking that sql types are somehow dedicated types for JPA Spec - I will use `byte[]` or `String` and leave rest for ORM as You suggesting

Comment: One more thing which comes to my mind : isn't a problem to map (B/C)Lob as a `String` in my model vs Java String Pool - Will it not be cause of some memory problem in JVM?

Comment: Another obvious reason to do this (as @PawełDulęba also hinted) avoiding annotation-based Java type fields, would be to build stream-backed blobs for memory efficiency / when you are handling potentially large entities

Answer (score 2):

Because Hibernate.createBlob has been removed now from hibernate due to some enhancement (i don't remember exact jira issue :). you can find on internet).

So all you can use is new Hibernate.getLobCreator as something like below :

```
public Blob createBlob(your param) {
    return Hibernate.getLobCreator(currentSession()).createBlob();
}
// check different method for createBlob as you want to pass params.
// currentSession is method of HibernateDaoSupport 
// pass your session object instead of above
```

Here Blob is type of java.sql.Blob. Other blob methods for different class are implementing this interface. So you will get proper Blob either you are using oracle or sql server or anything....

So if you are using Hibernate 5.x.x then use like above.

Comment: If you use any recent version of Hibernate use a field annotated with `@Lob`.

Comment: On 5.5.7, faced some issues (class-cast exception from Hibernate internal code!) when trying `Hibernate.getLobCreator(session)` (had been using that for quite some time); so switched to `session.getLobHelper().createBlob..` instead

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found some soft of solution of how to initialize [Blob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) without accessing session object.

I used [SerialBlob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialBlob.html) implementation. Below is simple source code sample:

```
private Blob getBlob(String classpathLocation) {
    ClassPathResource imageFile = new ClassPathResource(classpathLocation);

    Blob resource = null;
    if (imageFile.exists()) {

        try {
            try (InputStream inputStream = imageFile.getInputStream()) {
                resource = new SerialBlob(StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(inputStream));
                LOG.warn("Resource loaded from {}", classpathLocation);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(MessageFormat.format("Unable to load resource from {0}", classpathLocation), e);
        }
    } else {
        LOG.warn("Resource do not exist on {}", classpathLocation);
    }
    return resource;
}
```